# How to serialize an array of objects to form fields in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to  seriliaze  json like this  in my  form fields:

```
 {FinalResult: [{"id":1,"organizationNameGE":"პსდა2","organizatio…":"02-16-2018","$$hashKey":"0Q0","priority":"1"}]"}
```

and  for  this  reason i use  this  code:

```
<script cam-script type="text/form-script">

    camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
      // tell the form SDK to fetch the variable named 'document'
      camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('selectedDocuments');
    });
    camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
      // work with the variable (bind it to the current AngularJS $scope)
      $scope.selectedDocuments =ConvertToJsonArray(camForm.variableManager.variableValue('selectedDocuments'));

    });
function ConvertToJsonArray(arr){
var jsonArray=arr.FinalResult;
return jsonArray;
}
  </script>
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in selectedDocuments track by $index">
<div class="control-group"  >
    <label for="id" class="control-label">საიდენტიფიკაციო კოდი</label>
     <div class="controls">
      <input id="id" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="item.id" required  readonly/>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="control-group" >
    <label for="cardNumber" class="control-label">ბარათის ნომერი</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="cardNumber" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.cardNumber" required />
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="control-group"  >
    <label for="organizationNameGE" class="control-label">კომპანიის სახელი ქართულად</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="organizationNameGE" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.organizationNameGE" required />
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="control-group"  >
    <label for="organizationNameEN" class="control-label">კომპანიის სახელი ლათინურად</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input id="organizationNameEN" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.organizationNameEN" required />
    </div>
  </div>    
   <div class="control-group" >
    <label for="Approved" class="control-label">Approved</label>  
   <input type="checkbox"
       class="form-control" 
       cam-variable-name="Approved"
       cam-variable-type="Boolean"/> 
       </div>       
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="refusalComment" class="control-label">კომენტარი უარზე</label>
      <input type="text"
           class="form-control" 
           cam-variable-type="String"
           cam-variable-name="refusalComment"
           name="კკომენტარი უარზედ"/>
            </div> 
            </div>
```

But this doesn't doesn't seem  to  be  enough, what  should  i  change  to  display  this json data  into  my form? should  i  use  ng-for  instead  of  ng-repeat?

(p.s  there is  no any internal  errors in console)

Comment: Use `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: you don't have to use *ngFor that is for angular and above. are you getting any error?

Comment: where  should  i use  $scope.$apply()?

Comment: you can use `ng-bind` instead of `ng-model` .

Comment: I think  that  ng-repeat  can   work only on arrays that's  why  i can't  place  item  data in  my  form  inputs

Comment: thats right but selectedDocuments  is also a array as per the json you gave .

Answer (score -1):

It looks you are taking data in the array FinalResult. 
Iam not sure why you used selectedDocuments .

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in selectedDocuments track by $index">
```

Use this isntead of selectedDocuments

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in FinalResult track by $index">
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: why downvote for this? please add some explanation for this.